# Finding $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[m]x - 1}{\sqrt[n]x - 1}$

Tags: calculus

Find the limit, without using L'Hospital's rule
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[m]x - 1}{\sqrt[n]x - 1}.
$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DronDram The linked question has an answer where L'Hospital has not been used.

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{\sqrt[n]x-1}{\sqrt[m]x-1}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(1+h)^{1/n}-1}{(1+h)^{1/m}-1}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac hn+O(h^2)}{\dfrac  hm+O(h^2)}=?$$

Comment: @RobertZ, Thanks