# Finding a limit involving roots without derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to find the following limit
$$
\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{1+x^{1/7}}{1+x^{1/5}}
$$
using no derivatives. I've tried attempting to rationalize or divide by certain polynomials, but nothing has worked. It's simple using L'Hopital's rule, but that involves derivatives.

(I'm also wondering if the technique used to evaluate that limit could be extended to
$$
\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{1+x^{1/m}}{1+x^{1/n}} = \frac{n}{m} \qquad m,n\text{ odd}
$$
but that's not the main question.)

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032220/finding-lim-x-to-1-frac-sqrtmx-1-sqrtnx-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=\sqrt[35]{x}$, then $$
\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{1+x^{1/7}}{1+x^{1/5}}
=
\lim_{t\to-1}\frac{1+t^5}{1+t^7}= \lim_{t\to-1}\frac{(t+1)(t^4-t^3+t^2-t+1)}{(t+1)(t^6-t^5+...-t+1)}= {5\over 7}
$$

Comment: Does this not just shift the question to figuring out the second limit without derivatives instead? That's still a $0/0$ indeterminate form.

Comment: Not necesary, you can factorize iz as shown and then cancel it...

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the standard limit formula $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^n-a^n} {x-a} =na^{n-1}$$ We have $$\lim_{x\to - 1}\frac{1+x^{1/7}}{1+x^{1/5}}=\lim_{x\to - 1}\dfrac{\dfrac{x^{1/7}-(-1)^{1/7}}{x-(-1)}}{\dfrac{x^{1/5}-(-1)^{1/5}}{x-(-1)}}=\frac{1/7}{1/5}=\frac{5}{7}$$